# Как перезагрузить часть экрана с видео

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, видео

Какие есть способы обновления части экрана с тегом div или video без jquery? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Что значит обновление части страницы? Вам надо заново загрузить видео? Удалить и обратно вставить элемент?

Comment: Вместо одного видео оббновить и загрузить другое

Comment: Такс. Опишу мелкими подзадачами в теории должно сработать) 1. [Глубоко копируете элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) 2. [Назначаете нужные аттрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) 3. [Заменяете старый элемент новым](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)

Comment: Так если вы используете vue, то перерендер элемента должен произойти как только у вас обновятся данные.  Для лучшего понимания приложите код.

Comment: Кстати только заметил тег Vue (спасибо @Evgenii). Я когда увидел `без jquery` я подумал, что вы на чистом JS пишите. Тогда вам не нужны те манипулции что я описывал

Comment: Благодарю, за помощь, решила вопрос. Да оно само должно рендериться, но не делает